# Tricky special single quote symbol

Tags: java, regex, text, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I observed that there is a difference between the plain single quote `'` and single quote in the word document `’`.
I tried to find the ASCII values from an online ASCII value finder for both the letters. I can find the ASCII value for the first one, but I can not able find the ASCII for the later one(`’`).

Even I tried to find the ASCII value using JAVA program like:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
    char ch='\’';
    System.out.println((int)ch);
}
```

The Java program also giving an error while trying like this.

So, basically what is the problem with the `’` character?

One thing I know this `’` symbol can produced from a MS word document by typing single quote.

The character can copied into any editor, after copying into the notepad also the symbol will be remains same. But if we type a single quote it will come as plain single quote `'` only.

So, basically when we type a program in a Word document and copied to an IDE or some where else to execute it. Then it will be a problem, right? So, how to solve this problem?

What will be the solution other than replacing `’` with `'`?

This problem is not specifically related to any language. It is a general problem that every one should be aware.

Notable Edit:

```
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
    char ch='’';
    System.out.println((int)ch);
}
```

Which is giving 8217(as one of the answer suggested)

But still how to resolve the problem?

Comment: "The problem" being that most unicode characters cannot be represented in ASCII based character sets? Well. That will likely remain unresolved.

Comment: You can represent U+2019 _RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK_ in Java ASCII sources using the Unicode escape `\u2019`.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers have correctly pointed out that your apostrophe is not an ASCII character but a Unicode one, called [RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/).

The problem with having this character in source code is your lexer/compiler does not recognise this character as the beginning or end of a string or whatever else an apostrophe is used for in your language. So, it will not act like a normal apostrophe in your source.

You've already said you *don't* want to do a find and replace, so what you can do instead is make your text editor only use normal ASCII apostrophes.

If you're using Microsoft Word (which, I might add, is *not* a very good code editor) then you can disable "smart quotes" to get around this. There are instructions for how to do this in [Word 2007 onwards](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/change-curly-quotes-to-straight-quotes-and-vice-versa-HA010173242.aspx#BM13) and [Word 2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/change-curly-quotes-to-straight-quotes-and-vice-versa-HP005190124.aspx). I've tested this and it does indeed make Word only use straight apostrophes.

Alternatively, you could also use a font that doesn't contain a RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK glyph (if you can find one).